# Can't read conf file in playframework 2.5

Tags: scala, playframework, configuration

In playframework < 2.5 we can use

```
val value = Play.current.configuration.getString("confKey")
```

but in 2.5 we have warning

> method current in object Play is deprecated: This is a static reference to application, use DI instead

```
package tmp

object TmpObj {
    val confVal = ??? // read key-value from application.conf or *.conf
}
```

So, my question is - **"How can i read conf from any object in project use `DI`?"**

Please help me understand what i must write in **`??????`** to get value from `application.conf` or another `somePath/file.conf`

```
import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.Configuration

class AppConfig @Inject() (configuration: play.api.Configuration) {
  val someConfValue = configuration.underlying.getString("someConfValue")
}

object ConfigReader extends AppConfig(??????) {
  def getSomeConfValue() = someConfValue
}

println(ConfigReader.getSomeConfValue())
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Also, `object`s don't mix well with Dependency Injection.

Comment: @marcospereira  in object, for example... - val mongoClient = MongoClient( `hostFromConfig`, `portFromCOnfig`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this I created the file services/ConfigReader.scala

```
package services

import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.{Configuration, Environment}

class AppConfig @Inject()(playConfig: Configuration) {
  val dbHost: Option[String] = playConfig.getString("mydb.host")
  val dbPort: Option[Long] = playConfig.getLong("mydb.port")
}

object ConfigReader {
  val config = new AppConfig(Configuration.load(Environment.simple()))
  def getDbHost: String = config.dbHost.getOrElse("localhost")
  def getDbPort: Long = config.dbPort.getOrElse(27017)
}
```

I prescrib in the conf/application.conf

```
mydb {
  host = 192.168.0.0
  port = 1234
}
```

and I had the opportunity to access a config from any location by importing my ConfigReader, for example in controller

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._
import services.ConfigReader

class SomeCtrl extends Controller {
  def index = Action { request =>
    Ok(ConfigReader.getDbHost + ":" + ConfigReader.getDbPort.toString)
  }
}
```

its work fine, but i still want do this from `myconf/myconf.conf` and looking for a way

Answer (score 0):

Since AppConfig requires 'configuration' object, its instance creation requires that object. Having @Inject() notation just tells DI framework that it needs to provide this dependency at compile time.

So there are two ways to solve what you are trying to achieve:
Instead of defining object define a class ConfigReader:

```
class ConfigReader(config: play.api.Configuration) extends AppConfig(config) {
  def getSomeConfValue() = someConfValue
}
```

Or since you have introduced DI framework, let it handle all dependencies for you.

```
class ConfigReader @Inject() (appConfig: AppConfig) {
  def getSomeConfValue() = appConfig.someConfValue
}
```

Then wherever `ConfigReader` is needed inject that too.

Comment: i need object ConfigReader not class, anyway my question still stay about what i must transfer to new ConfigReader(???????) to get application.conf or any *.conf